# Moving Files from Command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a directory on a windows share with 15,000 files in it. What i want do is move 500 files to a new directory.

Is there a way to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

there is the code you need. saved it as a .bat file and run it:

```sh
echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set movedFiles=0
for /R c:\sourceFolder\ %%G in (*) do (
    echo moving... "%%G"
    move /Y "%%G" c:\destinationFolder\
    set /a movedFiles+="1"
    if !movedFiles! EQU 500 GOTO endOfCopy rem if you moved 500 files
  )
  :endOfCopy
  echo Done, %movedFiles% files Where copied successfully
  pause
ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 9):

You want some thing like this.Eg.
 `move c:\windows\temp\*.* c:\temp`

Comment: This question is tagged Windows 7 which doesn't support the `MOVE` command.

Comment: @cyroxx `move` is supported on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the appropriate command is called move. The syntax looks like this:

```
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination
```

You would write something like:

```
move Z:\directory\*.* c:\newdirectory
```

But the question is more appropriate for superuser.

Comment: but how do you control the number of files that are copied?

Comment: @Villumanati It looks I didn't understand your question right. Do you know which 500 files you want to move, or do you just want to limit the number to 500?

Comment: This question is tagged Windows 7 which doesn't support the `MOVE` command.

Comment: @cyroxx I don't know where you are getting this from. `move` is supported on Windows 7.

Comment: @ipavlic Sorry, you are right, that was an error on my side. Is there any way to remove the downvote? SO says its locked until the answer is edited.

Comment: @cyroxx I can usually just click on the upvote/downvote arrow again.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option for the **move** command that says "move the first 500 files". If you want to do something like that you'll need some sort of scripting language. [Batch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) is the native scripting language in the Windows command line, but it's cumbersome. [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419) is Microsoft's newest scripting language, it's supposed to be pretty powerful.